# Running DJI-SDK Android ImportSDKDemo is failing with INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

Tags: android, android-studio, dji-sdk

I followed the instructions in https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-integrate.html#android-studio-project-integration.
* The Android Studio project build is successful
* I created the API-KEY according to the instructions and populated it in the AndroidManifest.xml

When I click on run app on Nexus 5 emulator on my PC, the emulator is open and running but the installation of the DJI app is failing with the following  error:

04/01 20:54:58: Launching 'app' on Nexus 5X API 28 x86.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
Installation failed due to: 'null'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can't run DJI-SDK in emulator, you must use a physical device.
It might be possible, but it's nothing I recommend bother with.

Comment: Thanks, as you suggested I managed to deploy the app to my Android device and then run it with USB connection to the controller.

Comment: I recommend using DJI-bridge, then you can have your device connected to your computer while debugging.
https://github.com/dji-sdk/Android-Bridge-App

Comment: I tried to get it working with the emulator in 2 days, plugged in an android device, all repos I did work perfectly fine... DJI should have a big black text saying "DON'T USE THE EMULATOR"!!